# Excluding dependencies in Maven's dependency plugin

Tags: java, maven

In order to speed up my build process, which relies in `Docker`, I want to generate an image that contains all the `maven` dependencies already downloaded for my project.  For this, I am using `maven` `dependency` plugin, invoking the goal `dependency:resolve`.

My `maven` project contain two modules (`A` and `B`) and `B` depends on `A` in order for the build to succeed.  This means that when I invoke `dependency:resolve` goal, the process fails when it gets to the module `B` that depends on `A`, which has not been built yet (I use `-SNAPSHOT` versions in the `pom.xml` for my project).

I have tried excluding this dependency, but I cannot find a way to make it work.  How can this be done?

Comment: If B depends on A, then A is built first in the multi-module build.

Comment: I am not building anything.  Just invoking the `dependency:resolve` plugin which will download all the project/module dependencies.  This is the reason why it fails, because it does not build the dependent module.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue caused by me trying to achieve exactly the same goal using the same approach. All the combinations of options available affect the inclusion of artifacts in the resolution but oddly the plugin tries to retrieve the artifact before considering whether it should be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Maven [dependency plugin docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/resolve-mojo.html) you can use additional parameters including excludeArtifactIds.

> **excludeArtifactIds**
>   Comma separated list of Artifact names to exclude.
>   Type: java.lang.String
>   Since: 2.0
>   Required: No
>   User Property: excludeArtifactIds

This should help to achieve your goal without messing up your regular build process.

Comment: I tried this on my project and a different one.  It sadly does not work in the way I thought it would be.  If the dependency is available it will exclude later and not show it or download it.  If the dependency is not available, on the other hand it will fail and complain about it being missing;  Which is sadly my case.

Should a bug report be filled for this?